# How to filter content on Save/Publish to add rel="nofollow" to all external links?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm looking for a plugin or example of code that can intercept the save/publish event and verify that all external links within the post content have rel="nofollow" attributes.

Is it possible to use add_filter or add_action on the post save/publish event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try "wp_insert_post_data" filter.

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'new_content' );
function new_content($content) {    
    preg_match_all('~<a.*>~isU',$content["post_content"],$matches);
    for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof($matches[0]); $i++){

        if ( !preg_match( '~nofollow~is',$matches[0][$i]) ){
            $result = trim($matches[0][$i],">");
            $result .= ' rel="nofollow">';
            $content['post_content'] = str_replace($matches[0][$i], $result, $content['post_content']);
        }

    }

    return $content;
}
```

Obviously needs work, just a PoC.

Comment: **@Backie** Please explain how exactly you would try to use the `wp_insert_post_data` filter?

Comment: @EAMann added a little snippet of code.

Comment: @Backie, this works great, esp for a POC. Two comments: (1) How to alter the preg_match so that it skips over internal links? (2) Would there be an advantage to using "wp_insert_post_data" vs "content_save_pre"?

Comment: http://backie.org/2011/01/25/add-nofollow-to-external-links-in-wordpress/ does it for external only. Only a simple change made. I wasn't able to get content_save_pre filter to work. I may have been doing it wrong tho.

Comment: @Backie: Just commented on your solution. Works great. Only suggestion would be to place the rel at the end of the attrib list vs at the beginning...

Comment: For me it appears at the end of the tag. Shouldn't really matter where it is anyways.